# Find the structure of all permutations of arbitrary n digit numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

To make clear what is being asked, consider this restricted example: Find  permutation structure on 3 digits numbers, also using only digits 1,2,3.
The meaning of “structure” will be explained below.

We observe:
111, 222, and 333 have exactly 1 permutation each, namely themselves.
112, 113, 221, 223, 331, and 332 have exactly 3 permutations each.
123 has exactly 6 permutations.

There are 3 instances of 1 permutation, 6 instances of 3 permutations and one instance of 6 permutations. This accounts for all 3^3 possible combinations. What I want is how to determine the permutation structure for an arbitrary n digit number. In this case of 3 digits, the structure was:

## strings with Number of permutations=1, #instances=3

## strings with Number of permutations=3, #instances=6

## strings with Number of permutations=6, #instances=1

Comment: What happens for $n\ge10$? Do you want to consider digits other than $1-9$?

Comment: Just digits 0-9. The question is general, not limited to any particular number N. I used the case of 3 digits (and value 1,2,3 as digits) just for simplicity as an example.

Comment: Well if not limited to any particular $N$ then how exactly will you write the permutations for $11$ digits?

Comment: There is a distribution of combinations for a given number of digits. (not a specific number, but across all possible numbers with that number of digits). And those combinations each spawn a set of permutations. Treat it just like the 3 digit example.